# CSS responsive inner DIV not resizing to outer DIV width

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-specificity

I'm trying to make my site responsive using media queries. The outer DIV changes width but the width of the inner node(s) don't seem to change.

Purple is the outer DIV.

[image: Normal desktop size, Blue=DIV]

Inner text not changing with responsive size change.

[image: Smaller size, blue color=DIV]

The outer DIV gets smaller but the content stays the same width.

Here's the code:

```css
.main{
 margin: 0px;
 width:1200px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.auto-style3{
 margin:0px;
 background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 799px){
 .main{
  width:100%;
 }
 .auto-style3{
  width:100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="auto-style3" style="height: 100px; width: 1200px" >
        <h3 class="onama2"><b>O nama</b></h3>
        <h4 class="onama">Tvrtka Agrofit d.o.o. osnovana je 2012.godine s ciljem pružanja stručnog savjetovanja i ostalih usluga u poljoprivrednoj proizvodnji.
Proizvođače pratimo i savjetujemo "od sjetve do žetve" te svim partnerima nudimo <b>uslugu besplatne dostave za naše proizvode na području Republike Hrvatske.</b>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's plenty of CSS on SO for this already, try the "vw" property, it could scale to screen size with no media-queries.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777598/font-size-relative-to-the-users-screen-resolution

And please remove all inline styles!

Comment: The DIV with the auto-style3 class has a "style" attribute. Style attributes take higher priority over any other .class or #id rule definition. You have the width set to 1200px, hence the width will never change.

Comment: Cleaned up the code and simplified the question (to get to the point). This is a good learning exercise for understanding CSS Specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to apply a `max-width` to the `.auto-style3` element so that it doesn't exceed the width of it's parent element.

```css
.auto-style3 {
  margin: 0px;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7);
}

.main {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.auto-style3 {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  .main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .auto-style3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">

    <div class="auto-style3" style="height: auto; width: 1200px">
      <h3 class="onama2"><b>O nama</b></h3>
      <h4 class="onama">Tvrtka Agrofit d.o.o. osnovana je 2012.godine s ciljem pružanja stručnog savjetovanja i ostalih usluga u poljoprivrednoj proizvodnji. Proizvođače pratimo i savjetujemo "od sjetve do žetve" te svim partnerima nudimo <b>uslugu besplatne dostave za naše proizvode na području Republike Hrvatske.</b></h4>


    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do i need to put this in everything that is inside that div

Comment: You should probably apply it to any element with fixed widths and heights. I would go so far as to say avoid explicitly set widths and heights if you need to retain responsiveness and keep content dynamic. If you need to set explicit values, for whatever reason, try doing so with external styles (through your stylessheet) rather than inline styles, as inline styles carry more specificity and you'll have a headache trying to over-qualify them with your responsive styles (@media queries)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The options you have is either:
a) Use the `font-size` property to change the size of the font, or
b) use `overflow` on the container to make the content scrollable

EDIT: there are other options if you are happy for the text to wrap, see other answers on this question.

Comment: I want content to change with the div they are inside of

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a fixed width defined on the `.auto-style3` div. Remove the inline `style="height: 100px; width: 1200px"`

http://codepen.io/JKudla/pen/KWGgpP

Comment: Oh that means i cant have a fixed width or height on media query elements

Comment: No, you can. But when you put an inline style attribute on an html element, it will override any external css unless you put `!important` in the external css.

Comment: but if i remove .auto-style3 then on desktop(bigger screen size) it will look bad

Comment: You don't need to remove the class `.auto-style3`. You need to remove the style attribute that is applied the the `<div class="auto-style3" style="...">`

Comment: sorry wrote it wrong...... remove width and height and it will look bad on desktop