# Eclipse IDE scaling on Multi-Monitor with different resolutions

Tags: eclipse

I current have 3 monitors and was looking for a solution to fix the scaling between a 4K monitor and a 1080p monitor.

Most applications scale when switching monitors but Eclipse doesn't. The font is either large in 1080p or small in 4k. The zoom function sets the size for the whole application and not a single window.

Edit : I am using Eclipse Oxyen on  Windows 10

Comment: There are many known issues with using hi res displays with Eclipse. Please update your post (rather than adding a comment) to specify your operating system, and what version of Eclipse are you using.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to go about this.

## Windows 10

Customize the scaling of each monitor.

- Go to *Windows Settings > System > Display* page.
- Select the display to customize.
- Scroll to the *Scale and layout* section.
- Choose the % of the *Change the size of text, apps, and other items* option.
- Repeat for each monitor as desired.

## Eclipse IDE

Customize the CSS of themes.

- Close Eclipse.
- Edit the desired theme:

  ```
  $ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_XXX/css/**/*.css
  ```
- Restart Eclipse.

CSS has [multiple ways of specifying font size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). Supposedly there is even a means to [size fonts relative to screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777598/font-size-relative-to-the-users-screen-resolution). You'll have to play with [Eclipse's CSS engine](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS) to see what it supports.