# get display: inline responsive

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a portfolio and I want to get a display: inline element to work when the screen gets shorter.

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div>
  <p> Hello there! </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  margin: 80px;
}

div p {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  background: orange;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/bwn8c4gr/

When I resize the width of the web browser, you can't read the text and there is no 'padding-right' and 'padding-left' on the p-element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font size relative to the user's screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777598/font-size-relative-to-the-users-screen-resolution)

Comment: You can use media queries fi you want to make your site responsive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should use display:inline-block; instead only inline. padding, margin don't work properly with inline element.

Comment: I can't use inline-block, because I want the background to appear just behind the text

Answer (score 1):

The background of the various line boxes is overlapping. To stop that you need to move the line boxes further apart.

You need to ensure the `line-height` is at least as big as the `font-size` and the `padding-bottom` and the `padding-top`.

```
line-height: 170px;
```

Comment: I get that, thanks! But how do I get the text in he middle of the background, if possible?

Comment: @LMinor — Sounds like `display: inline` is the wrong approach if you want that

Comment: But what can I use then? Maybe with ::before and ::after, but that is a bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS styling in your responsive breakpoint:

the point is that you should control your text by "line-height" in responsive:

```
line-height: 2;
display: block;
text-align: center;
```